# Round-robining to aws kinesis streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

As an alternative to resharding which causes much latency how can we  dynamically create aws kinesis streams and **round-robin-ing** to streams?

Answer (score 0):

1. I have solved this partially by taking the sample stream messages of 2000 from the twitter hosebird- client.
2. I have created 3 AWS Kinesis Streams each getting 500 messages and calling the next AWS Kinesis  Stream by automatically(java - code).
3. For the last 500 messages the last stream again called the first stream.

Is this the right approach ?

> I am trying do this by the concept given in the book : Concepts of OS by Galvin and apply the same for multiple AWS Kinesis Streams.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10470819)

Comment: Sure , from next time